# Java: increment user input by 1 for each loop

Tags: java

I want the program to keep looping until the user inputs -33.
For each loop it displays 4 options for the user to vote on. 
After the user has voted, it increments the value for the painting which the user has voted on by 1 and then goes to the next round.

This is the code that I have at the moment and its not really working as I planned:

```
import javax.swing.*; // import swing lib for i/o
public class arrraa
{
static String[] painting = new String[4];//these have been made global and static
static int[] votescount = new int[4];

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    // Initialize String Arrays
    painting[0] = "Mona Lisa";//these have been moved so that it is only called once
    painting[1] = "Water Lillies";
    painting[2] = "The Scream";
    painting[3] = "A Young Rembrandt";
    // Initialize int Arrays

    votescount[0] = 0;
    votescount[1] = 0;
    votescount[2] = 0;
    votescount[3] = 0;


    voteperson();
    System.exit(0);
} // end method main

public static int voteperson()
{
    // Declare String Variables
    String userinput;
    userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
    ("Please tell us which painting you think is the best."+"\n"+
    "Vote 1 "+painting[0]+"\n"+
    "Vote 2 "+painting[1]+"\n"+
    "Vote 3 "+painting[2]+"\n"+
    "Vote 4 "+painting[3]);

    int answer = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
    System.out.println(answer);

        while(answer!=-33);
        {
            if (answer == 1)
            {
                votescount[0] = votescount[0]+1;
            }
            else if (answer == 2)
            {
                votescount[1] = votescount[1]+1;
            }
            else if (answer == 3)
            {
                votescount[2] = votescount[2]+1;
            }
            else if (answer == 4)
            {
                votescount[3] = votescount[3]+1;
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vote for one of these four paintings!");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
            (null, "The current votes are" + "\n" +
            votescount[0] + " :" + painting[0] + "\n" +
            votescount[1] + " :" + painting[1] + "\n" + 
            votescount[2] + " :" + painting[2] + "\n" +
            votescount[3] + " :" + painting[3]);

            answer++;
       }//ENDS LOOP


                return 0;
}//ENDS voteperson

}//ENDS CLASS
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is that you increment `answer` after each iteration. So it will go to infinity, but never to -33 and you end up in an endless loop.

Change your loop like so:

```
while(answer!=-33)
    {
        if (answer == 1)
        {
            votescount[0] = votescount[0]+1;
        }
        else if (answer == 2)
        {
            votescount[1] = votescount[1]+1;
        }
        else if (answer == 3)
        {
            votescount[2] = votescount[2]+1;
        }
        else if (answer == 4)
        {
            votescount[3] = votescount[3]+1;
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vote for one of these four paintings!");
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
        (null, "The current votes are" + "\n" +
        votescount[0] + " :" + painting[0] + "\n" +
        votescount[1] + " :" + painting[1] + "\n" + 
        votescount[2] + " :" + painting[2] + "\n" +
        votescount[3] + " :" + painting[3]);

        userinput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
        ("Please tell us which painting you think is the best."+"\n"+
        "Vote 1 "+painting[0]+"\n"+
        "Vote 2 "+painting[1]+"\n"+
        "Vote 3 "+painting[2]+"\n"+
        "Vote 4 "+painting[3]);

        answer = Integer.parseInt(userinput);
   }//ENDS LOOP
```

to ask for new user input after each iteration. That should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. When I removed the ";" i simply ended in an infinite loop. The correction that you suggested makes the program run as planned!

Answer (score 0):

You may try by removing the `semicolon ;` like this:

```
 while(answer!=-33)   //Remove the semicolon
```

instead of

```
 while(answer!=-33);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove semi-colon before while loop

**while(answer!=-33);**